# electron to angular communication

Tags: angular, electron, communication, web-content

I build an angular app and then wrapped it using Electron.
My dir structure looks like this :
Project
|--electron
---|-main.js
-----|-index.html (and other files copied from webapp/dist)
|--webapp (angular app)
---|-src
-----|-app
-------|-service

I tried inter-process communication (`ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer`) but it got hanged up!
Then I came to know about `webcontent.executeJavascript();`

So I made a service in angular which has a various functions like `eventFromHost()` & `sendMessage()`.

how do I call this function from electron's main.js using webcontent or any other method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer` for that:

In Angular:

```
ipcMain.send('foo', data);
```

In electron:

```
ipcMain.on('foo', (event, data) => {
  // Do what you want with data.
});
```

Or same using `ipcRenderer` to make electron => angular communication (`ipcMain` being to communicate from angular to electron).

If you want to see a live example, check [this main.js file](https://github.com/ffxiv-teamcraft/ffxiv-teamcraft/blob/master/desktop/main.js) on github, and the service that communicates with it [here](https://github.com/ffxiv-teamcraft/ffxiv-teamcraft/blob/staging/apps/client/src/app/core/electron/ipc.service.ts) in angular.

Comment: already tried but here the problem is I separated electron and angular, so I have to install separate electron instance for both and the can't communicate!

Comment: Separate electron instance? in the project I linked, electron is booting angular without knowing it is angular, so it shouldn't be an issue with separated electron

Comment: review the dir structure. I have package.json file in electron and webapp folder.

Comment: That's not an issue at all, because electron still boots your angular application, so in the end they are both linked. If angular runs inside an electron instance, window.require('electron') will have electron inside of it. see the ipc.service I linked to you, this is for both browser and electron. If electron isn't here, then the service doesn't load, that's all.

Comment: anything with `webcontent.executeJavascript();`